# Flutter How to remove certaint documents from a stream in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to stream documents from my collection orders.
Here I stream all documents in my collection orders where the parameter progress is equal to pool.

**This is how I do it:**

```
Stream<List<Order>> streamOrderPool() {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user!.uid;

    var ref = _db.collection('orders').where('progress', isEqualTo: 'pool');

    return ref.snapshots().map(
        (list) => list.docs.map((doc) => Order.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());

  }
```

What I want to do is to remove all documents where the parameter dismissedIds contains uid.

**This is how I solved it in a futurebuilder:**

```
 Future<List<Order>> getOrdersPool() async {
    
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user!.uid;

    var ref = _db.collection('orders').where('progress', isEqualTo: 'pool');

    var snapshot = await ref.get();
    var data = snapshot.docs.map((s) => s.data());

    var orders = data.map((d) => Order.fromJson(d));

   
    var orderslist = orders.toList();
    orderslist.removeWhere((order) => order.dismissedIds.contains(uid));
    orderslist.sort((b, a) => a.startDate.compareTo(b.startDate));

    return orderslist;
  }
```

How do I get the same result in a streambuilder, is it possible to use removeWhere somehow? How do I remove all documents from stream where dissmissedIds contains uid?

Comment: you need to call `Stream.where` to filter your stream, more here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

Comment: But what function? It should be something like .where('dismissedIds', arrayContains: uid); but with the inverse of arrayContains (arrayNotContains or something) which does not exist.

Comment: oops, it should be `Stream.map` method, where you can return the items that are not dismissed - you just need to change your `streamOrderPool()` method where `Stresm.map` is already used

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how? Ive tried in many ways but I cant figure out how since I havent got a good understanding in how .map, list and streams and so on works

Comment: "since I havent got a good understanding in how .map, list and streams and so on works" - check https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables then

Comment: That was not my question, I understand that you may not know how to solv it or you may not want to give direct help, but then it is pointless answering since its obvious that 90% of questions regarding flutter could be found in dart.dev, but thats not the point of the question.